# Does message rfc822 allow a new line between two headers?

Tags: email, mime, rfc, rfc822, rfc3339

Does message rfc822 allow a new line in between two headers?

After Content-Disposition I got a newline.
Attaching Image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Received header (and all of the headers that follow it) are not part of the MIME part headers - they are the content of the MIME part.

This attachment has a MIME-type of message/rfc822 which is an email message. When you parse the content of the MIME part (which starts with the Received header), what you end up with is another message object.

Comment: That's not entirely a correct analysis. The body part's headers are separate from the body part's contents, which are a `message/rfc822` part with a completely distinct set of headers.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I wrote because you just restated what I said in a different way.

Comment: If that's what you are trying to say, the first four words should probably not end with "yes".